# prependTo() doesn't add new element

Tags: jquery

I use [WowBook, a flipbook jQuery plugin](http://codecanyon.net/item/wowbook-a-flipbook-jquery-plugin/1791563) and I need to use thumbnails_generator.js for generation thumbnails.

I added this script on my page

```
<script src="Scripts/js/thumbnails_generator.js"></script>
```

but script doesn't work properly.

**thumbnails_generator.js**

```
;(function($) {

/* A lot of other functions */

function createUI(){
    console.log(1);
    var div = $("<div>").prependTo("body").css({
        background: "white",
        border:"1px solid black",
        position: "absolute",
        padding: "8px",
        zIndex: 100000,
        top: 0,
        left: 0
    });
    console.log(2);

    var button = $("<button style='position: relative; top:0; left: 0'>Generate Thumbnails</button>");
    button.appendTo(div);
    $("<div id='progress' style='display: none;'><span class='loaded'>0</span> / <span class='total'></span> pages loaded</div>").appendTo(div);
    var anchor = $("<a download='thumbnails.png' style='display:block'>Click to download thumbnails</a>");
    button.click(function(){
        var book = $.wowBook( $(".wowbook") );
        $('#progress').css("display", "block").find(".total").text( book.pages.length );
        loadAllPages( book, function(){
            var canvas  = createThumbnailsSprite( book );
            var data    = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
            anchor[0].href = data; // dt.replace(/^data:image\/[^;]/, 'data:application/octet-stream');
            div.append(anchor).append(canvas);
        })
    });
    return
} // createUI

createUI();


})(jQuery);
```

`console.log(1);` works and `console.log(2);` works too, but `var div = $("<div>").prependTo("body")` doesn't work, it doesn't add any new element on the page. I broke all my mind trying to understand what's wrong?

Comment: It runs fine....see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h76nzhc7/1/). Inspect the dom to find it, or to be sure it's really not there. Otherwise create a fiddle reproducing the issue and we can help.

Comment: Yes, it works fine in fiddle, but for example here http://heidel.orgfree.com/test/test.html I uploded test page. I get 1 and to 2 in console but not 'div' prepended to body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
createUI();
```

to this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    createUI();
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!! Actually I thought that `$(document).ready(function(){})` is the same `;(function($) {})(jQuery);` here.

Comment: Nope, actually very different things. One is a closure, the other is a call on doc ready (which can also be written as `$(function(){});`  )

Comment: I definitely need to learn this things better. Thanks a lot for help and the explanation!